# How do I limit results from webhose data feeds

Tags: python-3.x, webhose

```
def run_query(search_term):
"""
Given a string containing search terms (query), returns a list of   results from the Webhose API,
with each result consisting of a title, link and summary.
"""
webhose_api_key = read_webhose_key()

if not webhose_api_key:
    raise KeyError('webhose key not found')

try:
    search_term = search_term.strip()
    webhoseio.config(token=webhose_api_key)
    query_params = {"q": "\"{search_term}\" is_first:true language:english domain_rank:<100".format(search_term=search_term), "sort": "relevancy" }
    output = webhoseio.query("filterWebContent", query_params)

    results = []

    for post in output['posts']:
        results.append({'title': post['title'],
                        'link': post['url'],
                        'summary': post['text'][:200]})

except:
    print("Error when querying the Webhose API")

return results
```

**New programmer here**. I'm integrating a webhose data feed into my django application. By default queries return the total number of results, however I only want to display the first N results based on my filter parameters. After reading through the API docs I haven't found a solution.

- How do I limit the number of results returned from a query?
- If there isn't a succinct solution available via the API, how can I do this using python since the keys aren't ordered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination. 
This is from webhose documentation

> from
>
> A paging parameter that works only for relevancy sort order.
>
> &from=100

https://docs.webhose.io/docs/getpost-parameters